# quartz jobs in a cluster running on wrong node

Tags: spring, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, phase

uI have an application that is clustered in a 2+2 setup where 2 machines are used in alpha product phase, and the other two are used for real customers. all machines are looking at the same database,
I need a job to run at midnight for each of the groups. one of the two alpha machines should get a job, and the other two should get another job.

I'm using Spring 3.0.5 with Quartz 1.8.5 with the following properties

```
phase=alpha
quartz.job.name=MY_JOB_${phase}
```

```
<bean id="quartzPropertiesFactoryBean" class="com.liveperson.kwo.quartz.QuartzPropertiesFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="AUTO"/>
    <constructor-arg value="MY_CLUSTER"/>
    <constructor-arg value="JobStoreTX"/>
    <constructor-arg value="StdJDBCDelegate"/>
    <constructor-arg value="true"/> //isClustered
    <constructor-arg value="false"/> //useProperties
</bean>

<bean name="runJobBean" class="org.quartz.JobDetail">
    <property name="name" value="${quartz.job.name}"/>
    <property name="jobClass" value="CLASS1"/>
    <property name="group" value="JOB-for-${quartz.job.name}"/>
    <property name="jobDataMap">
        <bean class="org.quartz.JobDataMap">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="quartzPropertiesFactoryBean"/>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlConnectorBean"/>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runJobBean"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerBean"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I define two jobs, one for alpha and another for production throw the phase property, and the problem I'm having is that the job I define for alpha phase runs on the node defined to production, how can I make the job defined for the alpha phase run only on machines defined for alpha?

Thanks!